# How is a TLS connection initiated after the TCP handshake?

Tags: apache, http, ssl, tcp, https

I'm playing around with **Wireshark** and I wondered if someone could explain what I'm seeing.

From a client, I complete a TCP handshake with my HTTPS Apache server, I then send a valid packet which is not a **Client Hello** message. The server immediately shuts down the connection with a `[FIN,ACK]`.

Could someone explain what decides how the connection is shut down? How does the OS know that this case is so different from a valid browser request (for instance) which sends the Client Hello. Is it the Apache code that decides or does it not even get that far up the stack?

Comment: If the service is configured for TLS, and the client doesn't send a `ClientHello`, what do you expect to happen? Fallback to clear text?

Comment: It is the Apache code that closes the connection, and the OS that actually sends the FIN.